# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError exception while retrieving tweets

Tags: spring, spring-social

I am developing an application that uses the Spring Social API to access a Twitter account.
The connection with the Twitter is established successfully. I am able to retrieve the number of followers, profile name and friends. When I try to retrieve the tweets of the user, I get the java.lang.NoSuchMethodError exception.

The full stack trace is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode.asLong()J
    at org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TweetDeserializer.deserialize(TweetDeserializer.java:42)
    at org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TweetDeserializer.deserialize(TweetDeserializer.java:37)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:93)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:25)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2131)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:136)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:415)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:213)
    at org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TimelineTemplate.getHomeTimeline(TimelineTemplate.java:58)
    at org.springframework.social.twitter.api.impl.TimelineTemplate.getHomeTimeline(TimelineTemplate.java:48)
    at com.mindtree.web.controller.SimpleContoller.handleRequest(SimpleContoller.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:863)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:756)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Spring Social makes use of the latest version of Jackson, which is version 1.9, and the method `JsonNode.asLong()` is new to version 1.9

Compare JavaDoc for [1.8](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.8/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode.html) and [1.9](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode.html)

Answer (score 0):

No problems with spring-social 1.0.1 and jackson 1.9.2. Latest spring-social packages supports jackson 1.9.

```
spring-social-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-social-twitter-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
jackson-all-1.9.2.jar
```

Query :

```
List<Tweet> tweets = twitterApi.timelineOperations().getHomeTimeline();
```

You can get the latest release from : http://www.springsource.org/spring-social